# TFS deleted pending files during get latest

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I've got an unfortunate problem here. I was working on a TFS solution in VS2013 on my work laptop. I have a workspace setup on the laptop. Rather than working on my laptop, I went ahead and copied the solution to my desktop and made a large amount of changes there.

When I was finished, I copied the files from my desktop back to the laptop. At first, Visual Studio/TFS didn't have the items under source control, so I went through and added the items to source control. However, when I went to do a get latest, TFS ended up deleting the all the files where I had made changes on my laptop, pretty much leaving me with a broken solution.

Thankfully, I still have a backup of the changes saved to a flash drive, but all the changes that I made once I copied the files back to my laptop appear to be gone.

When I'm looking at my source control bindings, almost every single project is listed as 'Invalid'. For whatever reason, it added an extra folder to the file location path.

```
Expected Location: C:\tfs\collectionName\branchName\[solution]
Binding Location:  C:\tfs\collectionName\branchName\branchName\[solution]
```

When I go to the pending changes tab, the included changes section is also messed up.

```
First Parent Node:  Physical Path
Second Parent Node: $\ProjectName\Branch
```

Under the first parent node, it looks like it has all of my changes, except it doesn't have an action next to the file name, Add, Merge, Change, etc.

The second parent node seems to have very few of my changes, except the changes that it does have listed, have a file action.

I searched far and wide and it doesn't seem that anyone has run into this issue before.

### Update

I thought the source of the problem (pun-intended) was with the source bindings. However, there doesn't seem to be anyway for me to manually change the binding path. When I click 'Unbind' and 'Bind' again, there doesn't seem to be an option to change the path.

Comment: The source of the problem is the workflow that you are using. You should have a workspace mapped to your desktop and make changes there.

Answer (score 0):

Create a brand new workspace in a new folder on your laptop and make sure that it is a local workspace. ( no read only flagged)

Then open the workspace and delete all of your code. Then drop the new copy from your desktop to the correct location.

The local workspace scanner should detect all of the changes and make good guesses at renamed. You then only have to go through the file list manually add convert anything needs from add to rename.

**And don't do it that way again**